# Simulate negbin data from a fitted glmmTMB model - family negbin1

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I fitted a `glmmTMB` model using `family = nbinom1`. Now I would like to perform a simulation of data based on predicted values and the dispersion. However, from the help files, it looks like the go-to `rnbinom` function uses the `family=nbinom2` parameterization where variance is equal to `mu + mu^2/size`.

1) Can anyone help me figure out how to simulate `family=nbinom1` data (where variance is equal to `mu + mu*size`)?

2) Also, is my extraction / use of the dispersion value as size correct?

Thanks so much!

Current code (data not provided, because doesn't matter), using the `stats:::rnbinom` function despite the mismatch of variance definition:

```
library(glmmTMB)

mod <- glmmTMB(y ~ x + (1 | ID), data = df, family = nbinom1)
preds <- predict(mod, type = "response")
size <- sigma(mod)
sim <- rnbinom(nrow(df), mu = preds, size = size)
```

Comment: Can attempt a detailed answer later, you can easily work out the variance first using nbinom1 formula, calculate the size, and pass it back to rnbinom. size can be a vector as long as mu

Comment: sigma(mod) is ok.

Comment: True, good point. If you write up the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: if you just want to simulate from the observed predictors/fitted model there's a `simulate()` method for the fitted object (also good as a cross-check on any simulation you come up with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to simulate nbinom1, so if the variance is mu + mu*k:

```
set.seed(111)
k = 2
x = runif(100,min=1,max=3)
y = rnbinom(100,mu=exp(2*x),size=exp(2*x)/k)
ID = sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)
df = data.frame(x,y,ID)
mod <- glmmTMB(y ~ x + (1 | ID), data = df, family = nbinom1)

sigma(mod)
[1] 1.750076
```

In the above, for every mean, mu, I specified a size that is mu / k so that it will give an expected variance of mu*k. This shows that as long as you parameterize the rnbinom correctly, you get back rnbinom1.

Now with this model, if we need to simulate data, it's just using the same parameterization as above:

```
preds <- predict(mod, type = "response")
size <- sigma(mod)
sim <- rnbinom(nrow(df), mu = preds, size = preds/size)

plot(sim,df$y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of issues here, including:

- `sigma(mod)` gives the estimated standard deviation of the residuals; it is not a variance but the square-root of a variance, so you might want to square it.
- there are many parametrisations of a negative binomial distribution beyond R's version, but in R's version, if the mean is `mean(dat)` and the variance `var(dat)` then you can estimate `size` with `mean(dat)^2/(var(dat)-mean(dat))` and the probability `prob` with `mean(dat)/var(dat)`
- `rnbinom()` will tolerate `size` being non-integer or infinite despite this being a theoretical nonsense; it will not tolerate `size` being negative which can happen if  `var(dat)` is less than `mean(dat)`. It will also have problems the mean is negative or if `size` is zero.

So perhaps you could consider adapting your simulation lines to something like

```
sizes <- ifelse(sigma(mod) ^ 2 > preds, preds ^ 2 / (sigma(mod) ^ 2 - preds), Inf)
sim <- ifelse(preds > 0, rnbinom(nrow(df), mu = preds, size = sizes), 0)
```

then you might still get errors when `sigma(mod)` is less than or equal to `preds`

Comment: actually according to `?sigma.glmmTMB` "nbinom1 returns an overdispersion parameter (usually denoted alpha
          as in Hardin and Hilbe (2007)): such that the variance equals
          mu(1+alpha).

Comment: @BenBolker - you may well be correct: I had looked at the basic `?sigma`